# Word for a person who intentionally maligns someone's image in front of others

Tags: single-word-requests

I have faced such situation twice or thrice in my university and work life. Due to competition your peer or ill-wisher tries to put you in dark light intentionally. So, it gives wrong impression of you to other people. If your ill-wisher succeeds, then your image is spoiled in front of others without you actually doing any wrong.

So, what do you call a person who spoils your image or malign your image in public?

**For example:**  He is a/ an ____. He spoiled my image in my office.

In real, he did not spoil my image, but he tried and my co-workers supported me. One more thing, I use to use ill-wisher until now but I feel I need one perfect word. Using ill-wisher sounds stupid.

Comment: A character assassin.

Answer (score 1):

The richness of English for approximate synonyms suggests that you are far from being alone in having been upset by a:

*vilifier, traducer, disparager, denigrator, panner, defamer, knocker, and maligner!*

Most of those synonyms imply an element of untruth (libel, slander) so they may not quite express the meaning you seek.

Comment: It is more than criticizing me. He acts actively to malign my reputation. I checked all your suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Informally, he bad-mouths you.

Answer (score 1):

**Slanderer (noun):** a person who [slanders](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/slander) someone (= damages their reputation by making a false spoken statement about them). ([Cambridge English dictionary](http://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/slanderer))

**Examples:**

- I described him as a serial slanderer who poisoned political debate.
- The documents prove that they are liars and deliberate slanderers of my name.

(There's nothing wrong with 'ill-wisher'. You could also call him '[antagonist'](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/antagonist))

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a ***detractor***:
​
someone who criticizes something or someone, often unfairly:

// His detractors claim that his fierce temper makes him unsuitable for leadership.
(https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/detractor)

According to Oxford English Dictionary 
(https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/detractor):

***detractor***

NOUN

A person who disparages someone or something.

There's a list of synonyms:
critic, disparager, denigrator, deprecator, belittler, attacker, censurer, fault-finder, carper, backbiter, caviller, reviler, vilifier, slanderer, libeller, calumniator, defamer, traducer

Comment: not only by words but he also acts to malign me. like sending email from my workstation or something like that. thank you

Comment: "Maligner" is a synonym of "detractor".

Comment: yes yes.. but it is not just about speaking in evil manner but also doing wrong